# How to push textfield and dropdown values into state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am trying to render two fields text field and dropdown . Whenever user type something in text field I want to update it state . State object property must be array of object like `[{textFieldType:'text', value:'Hello'}]` . Same I want to do for dropdown `[{textFieldType:'text', value:'Hello'},{textFieldType:'dropdown',value:'Hello'}]` means I want to update state values by two fields . I am new could someone please help me .

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dy7zc3au/3/

**Code**

```
  state = {
    extraFields:[]
    }
    
   

      <td>
       <input
       type="text"
       className="inputStyle"
       placeholder={item.fieldName}
       value={optionalFields}
       />
     </td>
    <td>
    <select>
     <option>value 1</option>
     <option>value 2</option>
    </select>
    </td>
```

Comment: Can you please create demo of this on any of online env. so that can be worked on it easily?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dy7zc3au/3/

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        optionalFields: {}
    }
  }
  change(e) {
    const optionalFields = this.state.optionalFields;
        optionalFields[e.target.type] = e.target.value;
      this.setState({optionalFields})
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Optional Fields:</h2>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" onChange={(e) => {this.change(e)}}/>
       <br/><br/><br/>
       <select onChange={(e) => {this.change(e)}}>
         <option>value 1</option>
         <option>value 2</option>
       </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Use object instead of array that is more easy to control

example:

```
{
  select-one: "value 1",
  text: "a"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer , actually I need in array of object , because I need to add more stuff in object . Could you please change it . I want to like [{fieldName:'value 1', type:'text'} etc

Answer (score 0):

Check this codesandbox. There is more code since type is `select-one` and not `dropdown` as you want.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-wilson-fv5b8

Comment: sorry, i was working on some code changes. please try again :)

Comment: Actually, it working but face one issue . When ever I type for example I type ( what ) so it generated array like [ { fieldName:'w'},{ fieldName:'wh'},{ fieldName:'wha'},{ fieldName:'what'},] . I want to be single

Comment: can you try again? refresh the codesandbox page. it doent do that to me. check the console.log too. it always has 1 object inside array whenever i type in input text